# F# - (NUnit ApplyTo) member matches multiple overloads ... please restrict it to one

Tags: f#, fsunit

I'm trying to write custom equality constraint to compare 2 objects.

```ml
open FsUnit
open NUnit.Framework.Constraints

type equalCompany(expected:Company) = 
    inherit Constraints.EqualConstraint(expected)    

    override this.ApplyTo (actual:Company option) = 
        //actual.IsSome |> should equal True
        //actual.Value.Id |> should equal expected.Id

        ConstraintResult(this, actual, true)

// example of usage:
actualCompany |> should equalCompany expectedCompany
```

It complains because the ApplyTo implementation **matches multiple overloads** and I can't find the right syntax.
Ideally I like to compare to *Company option* but still just *Company* is fine.

The types involved are the following:

```ml
type CompanyType =
    | Bank
    | Exchange

type Company = {
    Id: string
    Types: CompanyType list
}
```

and I'm trying to write my equality constraint because the simple existing *equal* does not work properly with Types (the list, also if sorted, appears always different)

How can I properly override the *ApplyTo* function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is that the `ApplyTo` method that you are trying to override is generic and needs to have a signature `ApplyTo<'T> : 'T -> ConstraintResult`.

If I understand your code correctly, you are trying to define a comparison between `Company` and `Company option`. To Do this, you would need to check (at runtime) that the value passed to `ApplyTo` is of the right type. Then you can cast it and implement whatever logic you need.

Here is a minimal sample that worked for me, written as an F# script file:

```
#r "nuget: nunit"
#r "nuget: fsunit"

type Company(s) = 
  member x.Name = s

open FsUnit
open NUnit.Framework.Constraints

type equalCompany(expected:Company) = 
    inherit EqualConstraint(expected)    

    override this.ApplyTo<'T>(actual:'T) = 
        match box actual with 
        | :? option<Company> as co ->
          ConstraintResult(this, actual, 
            co.IsSome && co.Value.Name = expected.Name)
        | _ ->
          ConstraintResult(this, actual, false)

let actualCompany = Company("Test")
let expectedCompany = Company("Test")

// This passes, because it has the right type
Some actualCompany |> should equalCompany expectedCompany

// This does not, because the 'ApplyTo' logic does not handle this type
actualCompany |> should equalCompany expectedCompany
```